# Unable to Apply Middleware to Router in ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an app where I have public routes and authenticated routes. **isAuthenticated** were applied for example to a news controller.

```
globalRouter: function (app) {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    logger.log("Endpoint: ", req.originalUrl);
    next();
  });
  const userRouter = require("./user/controller");
  const globalRouter = require("./global/controller");
  const newsRouter = require("./news/controller");

  app.use("/user", userRouter);
  app.use("/global", globalRouter);
  app.use("/news", middleware.isAuthenticated(), newsRouter); // here
}
```

And here is the **isAuthenticated** code written in middleware.js file.

```
const security = require("../utils/security");
const service = require("../user/service");

exports.isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  let authorization = req.headers.authorization;
  let token = null;
  if (authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    token = authorization.substring(7, authorization.length);
    if (token !== null) {
      service.checkUserTokenMiddleware(token, security).then((response) => {
        console.log("checkUserTokenMiddleware", response);
        if (response) {
          next();
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error below when I **npm start** the app

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined at Object.exports.isAuthenticated

What am I missing here?

why do I get such an error meanwhile in my other file using the same method like **req.body.blabla** or **req.headers.blabla** is fine?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: You have called the function in the args to ```app.use```. You should be passing the function instead of calling it. Remove the ```()``` after ```isAuthenticated``` in ```app.use```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you import, `middleware.js`. Since you are exporting, `isAuthenticated` as function. This should be not called before passing to `app.use`.

Other things to be noticed, you never call the next function on error or else.

Please have a look in the below example.

// middleware.js

```
const security = require("../utils/security");
const service = require("../user/service");

exports.isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  let authorization = req.headers.authorization;
  let token = null;
  if (authorization.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    token = authorization.substring(7, authorization.length);
    if (token !== null) {
      service
        .checkUserTokenMiddleware(token, security)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response) {
            next();
          }
        })
        .catch((error) => next(error));
    } else {
      next("UNAUTHORIZED");
    }
  } else {
    next("UNAUTHORIZED");
  }
};
```

// app.js

```
const middleware = require("./middleware")

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  logger.log("Endpoint: ", req.originalUrl);
  next();
});
const userRouter = require("./user/controller");
const globalRouter = require("./global/controller");
const newsRouter = require("./news/controller");

app.use("/user", userRouter);
app.use("/global", globalRouter);
app.use("/news", middleware.isAuthenticated, newsRouter); // here
```

Comment: My bad. After digging more into controller and middleware. The problem lies in the controller which is not returning/resolving the promise. I also changed middleware.isAuthenticated() to middleware.isAuthenticated and then comes another error. But now everything's fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the brackets after the function call:

```js
app.use("/news", middleware.isAuthenticated, newsRouter);
```

You don't have to call the function in the callback to `app.use`, Express will itself pass in `req,res,next` to the auth function and call it.

Comment: thanks for the hint, well I changed it to ***app.use("/news", middleware.isAuthenticated, newsRouter);*** but then getting this another error: ***TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object***

Comment: My bad. After digging more into controller and middleware. The problem lies in the controller which is not returning/resolving the promise. I also changed middleware.isAuthenticated() to middleware.isAuthenticated and then comes another error. But now everything's fine. @xdeepakv explain more details but I'll drop an upvote on this answer too. Cheers. Thank you.